# Is it possible to skip filters if given predicate is null?

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to implement some filters inside my repository. The question I am asking myself is if it is possible to skip some filters like `orderBy()` if the given `queryHolder.order` is null.

Currently, I am just doing a null check and copy the rest. But this looks very ugly and not very handy.

### Current Approach

```
suspend fun testQuery(queryHolder: QueryHolder): QuerySnapshot = if (queryHolder.order != null) {
        db.collection(FIREBASE_PRODUCTS_BASE_PATH)
            .limit(SHOP_DB_DOCUMENT_LIMIT)
            .whereEqualTo(FIREBASE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY, queryHolder.category)
            .orderBy(queryHolder.order, queryHolder.orderAscending!!) <-- Would like to skip this, if null
            .get()
            .await()
    } else {
        db.collection(FIREBASE_PRODUCTS_BASE_PATH)
            .limit(SHOP_DB_DOCUMENT_LIMIT)
            .whereEqualTo(FIREBASE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY, queryHolder.category)
            .get()
            .await()
    }
```

Another problem with this approach is, that does not cover all cases, for example, I would like to have my `queryHolder.category` to be nullable too so that I am getting my entire cloud firestore list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize `apply{ }` to conditionally affect the building of the query before `get()` is being called:

```kotlin
        db.collection(FIREBASE_PRODUCTS_BASE_PATH)
            .limit(SHOP_DB_DOCUMENT_LIMIT)
            .whereEqualTo(FIREBASE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY, queryHolder.category)
            .apply{
               if(queryHolder.order != null){
                 orderBy(queryHolder.order, queryHolder.orderAscending!!)
               }
            }.get().await()
```